# Visual Basic - invoking .net runtime

Tags: .net, vba, excel, com

I am trying to invoke objects from .net runtime from VBA (Word/Excel).
This works:

`oT = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding")`

But not this: 

`CreateObject("System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceFactory")`

The error is:
Runtime error '429' ; ActiveX component can't create object

What I don't understand is how Excel/Word determines which classes are exposed and which aren't

Comment: Simple: Excel/Word doesn't even remotely get involved. It's the VBE's job, not the host application's.

Comment: So how would VBE know what is accessible and what is not?

Comment: Only a subset of the .NET classes are [ComVisible(true)].  Mostly the stuff that was in .NET 1.0, back when it was still important to get programmers to move on the .NET bandwagon and not force them to rewrite everything they had.  You'll have to create your own [ComVisible] wrapper.

Comment: It's fine, forgot to UV it, sorry.

Comment: @hans-passant that’s very helpful. Is there a list of exposed .net classes? They aren’t registered as progids, for example he System.Text seemingly isn’t.

Comment: Just look at the type libraries (*.tlb) in the framework folder with OleView.exe's File > View Typelib command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument you specify when invoking `CreateObject` is not a *namespace*, it's a `ProgId` - a string COM uses to locate registered classes (and the library they're defined in, and where that library is located), in the Windows Registry.

If there's no registered COM type with a `ProgId` value of `System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceFactory`, then ActiveX can't create that object.

If there's no COM type library for a namespace (i.e. the assembly isn't registered for COM interop), then you're trying to get COM to understand .NET/managed code, which it can't do.

> *What I don't understand is how Excel/Word determines which classes are exposed and which aren't*

Excel/Word/whatever host application has nothing to do with it, it's VBA's own runtime that loads the COM types, and it's the Windows Registry that contains the `ProgId` for everything that's registered.

If you search your registry for `Scripting.Dictionary` under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID`, you'll eventually find a key named `{EE09B103-97E0-11CF-978F-00A02463E06F}`, with a `ProgID` subkey having a value of `Scripting.Dictionary` and an `InprocServer32` subkey with a value of `C:\Windows\system32\scrrun.dll`, and if the VBA runtime succeeds at creating an instance of the type with the specified `ProgId` in that type library, then the `CreateObject` call succeeds and returns the instance. Otherwise, it throws an error 429 and says "ActiveX can't create object".

Comment: FWIW - `ProgId` is not strictly required for a `CreateObject` - a CLSID can be used in its place which can be helpful in some cases where a COM-compliant object don't have a `ProgID`. A good example is the `MSForms.DataObject` from MS Forms 2.0 Library which lacks a `ProgID`: `Set objData = CreateObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")`